# Connecting a PHP page to Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am the handler of my School's Website. I have a problem regarding updation of some images on site but these images should be open by their unique number. I don't get any idea to how to create the database of images in wordpress and link them with textbox.
i am sharing a snapshot of the work which i want to do.

[image: Snapshot]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is unclear totally. Do you have custom php page that you want to integrate WordPress with and pull out the images from there?

Comment: sir actually i want to extract some images by input their number in wordpress site. what should i do for this.